# using string value instade of array name in vba

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

i have some array and a combobox in excel vba, when from is active program set hozelistname value to combobox1. arrays is like below:

```
hozelistname=("zahedan","zabol")
hozezahedan=(1,2,3,4)
hozezaol=(5,6,7)
```

now when combobox1 change, i want it show the list of selected array. for example when i select zahedan from list i want it alert the value of zahedan array named hozezahedan and also for zabol.
i wrote the below code but not working! any body to help me?

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()    
  dim arrayname,str as string
  dim i as integer
  arrayname = "hoze" & ComboBox1.text

  for i= lbound(arrayname) to ubound(arrayname)
     msgbox(arryname(i))
  next
End Sub
```

Comment: Add you arrays to a dictionary and name them using the key.  something like dictionary.add "Hoze_Test",arrTest())  then you can reference using the key of "Hoze_Test" set arrUse=dictionary("Hoze_Test") this is not tested code, just advice, have a look at dictionaries.

Comment: can u write the correct code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Private dicArrays As Scripting.Dictionary

Sub SetUP()

Dim arrTestOne(5) As String
Dim arrTestTwo(10) As String

Set dicArrays = New Scripting.Dictionary

dicArrays.Add "TestOne", arrTestOne
dicArrays.Add "TestTwo", arrTestTwo

End Sub

Sub Reference_Example()

Dim a() As String

a = dicArrays("TestTwo")

End Sub
```

I hope this explains a little better.

Comment: u think that my array is big like hozename(hoze1 ... hoze50). and for each item i have another array, for example i need to write `dicArrays.Add "hoze1", arrhoze1, ..... dicArrays.Add "hoze50", arrhoze50`    ?

Comment: it have an error " `user-definde type not definde` "

Comment: You will have to include the reference for Scripting.Dictionary class. In VBEditor, go to Tools -> References and select/check 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime' and click on Ok button

Answer (score 0):

Its unclear what you are after but does the below help you through it?

```
'This block of code goes right at the top of the form
Option Explicit
Dim hozelistname(1) As String
Dim hozezahedan(3)  As String
Dim hozezabol(2)    As String

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim i           As Integer
Dim AryLocal()  As String

'set the local array based on the combobox
Select Case Me.ComboBox1

    Case "zahedan"
        AryLocal = hozezahedan

    Case "zabol"
        AryLocal = hozezabol

    Case Else
        ReDim AryLocal(0)

End Select

'show the local array
For i = 0 To UBound(AryLocal, 1)
   MsgBox (AryLocal(i))
Next

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Dim LngCounter As Long

'Set up the lists
hozelistname(0) = "zahedan"
hozelistname(1) = "zabol"

'Set up each result
hozezahedan(0) = "1"
hozezahedan(1) = "2"
hozezahedan(2) = "3"
hozezahedan(3) = "4"
hozezabol(0) = "5"
hozezabol(1) = "6"
hozezabol(2) = "7"

'set the combobox
For LngCounter = 0 To UBound(hozelistname, 1)
    Me.ComboBox1.AddItem hozelistname(LngCounter)
Next

End Sub
```

The next steps would be populating the ComboBox and arrays based on list written in Excel and not hardcoded ones.